# Please add a comment explaining the reason when voting to close a question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, comments

If you are voting to close a question, please explain the reason.

There are some questions which are closed with no explanations in the comments (two about careers). Not everyone reads the discussions on the meta and since we don't have a FAQ it can be quite confusing for other users why their questions has got closed if you don't explain it.

Comment: This also helps the moderators, because then they don't have to add that comment for you. Which helps speed up the moderation process and hopefully allows the moderators to do 'normal' stuff too

Comment: And as a side benefit comments by regular community members help make moderators not look like crazy dictators.